# CSS/Javascript Not Applying In Production

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a rails app with CSS/JS that works fine in development. In production, precompilation of assets goes fine. The resources are in the right locations, and everything is linked properly as far as I can tell.

The problem is, despite having the seemingly correct CSS in these files, it's not actually applying on the page. What does work is if I go into the editor, cut all the compiled CSS and repaste it. Then all the CSS applies.

```
Production.rb

config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.log_level = :debug
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

nginx.conf partial
server {
            listen 80 default;
            server_name example.com;

            root /home/appuser/current/public;
            # access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
            rewrite_log on;

            location / {
                    #all requests are sent to the UNIX socket
                    proxy_pass  http://example;
                    proxy_redirect     off;

                    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                    client_max_body_size       10m;
                    client_body_buffer_size    128k;

                    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
                    proxy_send_timeout         90;
                    proxy_read_timeout         90;

                    proxy_buffer_size          4k;
                    proxy_buffers              4 32k;
                    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
                    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
            }

            location ~ ^/assets/  {
                    root /home/appuser/current/public;
                    gzip_static on;
                    expires max;
                    add_header Cache_Control public;
            }

    }
```

Comment: When viewing the source of the page on production, are you able to click application.css and application.js (in the `<head>`) and see the compressed css and js files? That would check if the files are in fact in the right places / actually being loaded.

Comment: Yes, I can see the CSS. I'll reexplain. From the linked css in my html, I click on that in chrome and it takes me to the CSS (that's not being applied, probably due to a timing issue with nginx). If I cut that text and repaste it back in the same window, it works fine. When I removed nginx's ability to serve static assets and set serve_static_assets = true in production.rb, it works fine. Trying to set nginx to do this.

Comment: There's a host of defaults that Rails assumes for environments with the name 'development' and 'production' and so on. You don't have to declare compressed assets in environment/production.rb. The fix may be to remove some of the `config.assets` lines.

Comment: It's working now. Posted my answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, the CSS (and JS) was being loaded after the page was. I moved the asset block in the nginx config above the root location block and now things are working.